# Selecting element on webpage that exists in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I have a calendar app that accepts user inputs and stores them in `state` in the following format

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState([
    {
      title: "Finish Calendar",
      start: moment(),
      end: moment(),
      allDay: false,
    },
  ]);
```

And new elements are added as such

```
 const addEvent = (e) => {
    const newEvents = [...events];
    newEvents.push({
      title: eventValue,
      start: moment().date(startValue),
      end: moment().date(startValue),
    });
   
    setEvents(newEvents);
  };
```

I want to make the elements that are already on the calendar editable by clicking on them. They will be editable through the input that they are added (this can change if needed).

So far I have thought of using an `addEventListener` however I am new to using those in React, and even newer to React hooks.
So far I have a basic useEffect code that I am not sure how to work with.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('click', handler, passive)
  return () => {
    cleanup
  }
}, [input])
```

How do I allow the manipulation the state of an object by clicking on it?  
My full code is [Here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/AimhighChallege/blob/master/src/App.js) and here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-sun-9xv0i)

I appreciate your help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[onSelectEvent](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-onSelectSlot)

> Callback fired when a calendar event is selected.
>
> ```
> (event: Object, e: SyntheticEvent) => any
> ```

Add an `onSelectEvent` handler to your `Calendar` component. For example:

```
<Calendar
  localizer={localizer}
  defaultDate={new Date()}
  defaultView="month"
  views={allViews}
  events={events}
  style={{ height: "65vh" }}
  onSelectEvent={(event, e) => console.log('Selected event', event)}
/>
```

[image: Edit selecting-element-on-webpage-that-exists-in-state]

Notice in the sandbox I've introduced an `id` property for each calendar object. Use this `id` to identify ***what*** in state you want to modify. Sounds like you want to edit an existing entry using the existing "add event" API. This won't work as it will always add a new entry to your state.

Introduce an "edit mode" and if the `onSelectEvent` is clicked then toggle edit mode on and populate your "form" fields, and when `addEvent` is clicked either edit existing state if edit mode is true, or append event to end of `events` array.

It's really up to you how to handle your UI and behavior once you have identified the event the user clicked on. Let us know.

## Edit

Adding an "edit mode"

1. Add state to hold an event that you want to edit (used to identify events array element, and populate inputs for editing.
2. Update `addEvent` to handle either updating an existing event object or adding a new event object.
3. Convert inputs to be fully controlled (so they can be populated for editing).
4. Clear inputs/input state when adding/editing complete.

Code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [editEvent, setEditEvent] = useState(null);
  const [eventTitle, setEventTitle] = useState("");
  const [eventStart, setEventStart] = useState("");
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([
    {
      id: uuidV4(),
      title: "Finish Calendar",
      start: moment(),
      end: moment(),
      allDay: false
    }
  ]);

  const addEvent = (e) => {
    if (editEvent) {
      setEvents((events) =>
        events.map((event) =>
          event.id === editEvent.id
            ? {
                ...event,
                title: eventTitle,
                start: eventStart,
                end: eventStart
              }
            : event
        )
      );
      setEditEvent(null);
    } else {
      setEvents((events) => [
        ...events,
        {
          id: uuidV4(),
          title: eventTitle,
          start: moment().date(eventStart),
          end: moment().date(eventStart)
        }
      ]);
    }
    setEventTitle("");
    setEventStart("");
  };

  const selectEventHandler = (event, e) => setEditEvent(event);

  const cancelEditMode = () => setEditEvent(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editEvent) {
      setEventTitle(editEvent.title);
      setEventStart(editEvent.start);
    }
  }, [editEvent]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("events", events);
  }, [events]);

  const startOfMonth = moment().startOf("month").format("DD");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="text-center">
        <div className="event-input">
          <label>
            Event:
            <input
              id="eventInput"
              name="eventInput"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setEventTitle(e.target.value);
              }}
              value={eventTitle}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Start:
            <input
              id="startInput"
              name="startInput"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setEventStart(
                  parseInt(startOfMonth) + parseInt(e.target.value) - 1
                );
              }}
              value={eventStart}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <button type="button" onClick={addEvent}>
            {editEvent ? "Edit" : "Add"} event
          </button>
          {editEvent && (
            <button type="button" onClick={cancelEditMode}>
              Cancel
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        defaultView="month"
        views={allViews}
        events={events}
        style={{ height: "65vh" }}
        onSelectEvent={selectEventHandler}
      />
      <div className="row">
        <div className="list col-sm-6">
          <ul>
            <li>Display Weekly view (X)</li>
            <li>Highlight today (X)</li>
            <li>Allow navigation to different weeks (X)</li>
            <li>allow adding new events (X)</li>
            <li>allow editing existing events</li>
            <li>allow deleting events </li>
            <li>Persisting data (ran out of time)</li>
            <li>Use apis to load and save data (ran out of time)</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit selecting-element-on-webpage-that-exists-in-state (forked)]

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I was looking for the solution in the wrong place. I also have a small favor to ask, could you elaborate more on how I would introduce an ```edit mode```? I understand the concept but I don't know how to translate that into code.

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp Right, no worries. I almost implemented it in the first sandbox, but that part didn't appear to be your main question/issue and requires a little bit of extra state and logic. I will fork and add a second sandbox with how I'd do it.

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp Added new code and sandbox. Enjoy.

Comment: You are a saint, I really thank you for your help! I am going to study your code for days.